# XSL Transformation to create XML nodes dynamically

Tags: xslt

## Source XML :

```
<AWARD>
  <FIELD1>XYZ</FIELD1>
  <AWARDLINE>
     <ALINENUM>1</ALINENUM>
     <SHIPMENT>
        <SHIPLINENUM>1.1</SHIPLINENUM>
        <ACCOUNT>
          <ACCOUNTLINENUM>1.1.1</ACCOUNTLINENUM>
          <ASSOCIATEDREQ>
            <AREQNUM>1.1.1.1</AREQNUM>
          </ASSOCIATEDREQ>
        </ACCOUNT>
    </SHIPMENT>     
  </AWARDLINE>   
    <AWARDLINE>
     <ALINENUM>2</ALINENUM>
  </AWARDLINE>     
</AWARD>
```

Apart from AWARD all the child nodes "AWARDLINE" , "SHIPMENT", "ACCOUNT", "ASSOCIATEDREQ" may exist or may not exist.
  As seen above, AWARDLINE 2 does not have SHIPMENT/ACCOUNT/ASSOCIATEDREQ nodes.

Desired Target XML

```
<AWARD>
  <FIELD1>XYZ</FIELD1>
  <AWARDLINE>
     <ALINENUM>1</ALINENUM>
     <SHIPMENT>
        <SHIPLINENUM>1.1</SHIPLINENUM>
        <ACCOUNT>
          <ACCOUNTLINENUM>1.1.1</ACCOUNTLINENUM>
          <ASSOCIATEDREQ>
            <AREQNUM>1.1.1.1</AREQNUM>
          </ASSOCIATEDREQ>
        </ACCOUNT>
    </SHIPMENT>     
  </AWARDLINE>   
  <AWARDLINE>
     <ALINENUM>2</ALINENUM>
     <SHIPMENT> 
       <ACCOUNT>
         </ASSOCIATEDREQ>
       </ACCOUNT>
     </SHIPMENT>
  </AWARDLINE>     
</AWARD>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this XSLT-1.0 which does a replacement of all relevant nodes if they are present. It does selectively reconstruct the structure of the `AWARDLINE` element and works in combination with the *identity template*.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <!-- identity template -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- reconstruction of the AWARDLINE element structure -->
  <xsl:template match="AWARDLINE">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*[not(self::SHIPMENT)]" />
        <SHIPMENT>
            <xsl:copy-of select="SHIPMENT/*[not(self::ACCOUNT)]" />
            <ACCOUNT>
                <xsl:copy-of select="SHIPMENT/ACCOUNT/*[not(self::ASSOCIATEDREQ)]" />
                <ASSOCIATEDREQ>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="SHIPMENT/ACCOUNT/ASSOCIATEDREQ/*" />
                </ASSOCIATEDREQ>
            </ACCOUNT>
        </SHIPMENT> 
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Another possibility is using templates. This can process more than one `SHIPMENT` element and creates the empty structure if no other elements are present.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <!-- identity template -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- reconstruction of the AWARDLINE element structure -->
  <xsl:template match="AWARDLINE">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*[not(self::SHIPMENT)]|@*" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="SHIPMENT" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="AWARDLINE[not(SHIPMENT)]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*|@*" />
        <SHIPMENT>
          <ACCOUNT>
            <ASSOCIATEDREQ />
          </ACCOUNT>
        </SHIPMENT>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="SHIPMENT">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*[not(self::ACCOUNT)]|@*" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ACCOUNT" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="SHIPMENT[not(ACCOUNT)]">  
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*|@*" />
        <ACCOUNT>
          <ASSOCIATEDREQ />
        </ACCOUNT>
    </xsl:copy>   
  </xsl:template>  

  <xsl:template match="ACCOUNT">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*[not(self::ASSOCIATEDREQ)]|@*" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ASSOCIATEDREQ" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>  

  <xsl:template match="ACCOUNT[not(ASSOCIATEDREQ)]">  
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*|@*" />
        <ASSOCIATEDREQ />
    </xsl:copy>   
  </xsl:template>  

  <xsl:template match="ASSOCIATEDREQ">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. For the sake of simplicity in explaining the problem, I put only one element under AWARDLINE (ALINENUM) but there are around 30 different elements under AWARDLINE. Is there a way we could avoid doing this                                                     "<ALINENUM><xsl:value-of select="ALINENUM" /></ALINENUM>" for each element under AWARDLINE.  Basically a way to copy all elements under AWARDLINE as-is and then do the addition of nodes under AWARDLINE if they dont exist. I will keep trying from my end too. Thanks again for the pointers.

Comment: The same is applicable to the elements under SHIPMENT, ACCOUNT and ASSOCIATEDREQNUM nodes as well. We have many elements under each of these parent nodes and I am hoping there is a better way to not put every if test and value of select for each element under all of these nodes.

Comment: I updated my answer. My previous solution wasn't good, sorry for that. Now it copies every element under AWARDLINE, SHIPMENT, ACCOUNT and ASSOCIATEDREQNUM except for those that should be there all the time.

Comment: I think this solution looks good. I will test it more. Thanks again for the quick response and timely help.

Comment: I see a problem in this . If we have multiple SHIPMENT nodes under AWARDLINE, then only the first SHIPMENT content comes up and the rest of the content is lost. The same is with ACCOUNT tags as well.  I will continue researching on this. If you find anything , please update.

Comment: The empty structure of  SHIPMENT, ACCOUNT and ASSOCIATEDREQNUM is needed for further processing in my logic. I will continue to check further. Thanks

Comment: I extended the answer. This second version's templates should fulfill all requirements.

Comment: Thanks, I tested it for a few scenarios and it has worked every time. I will continue to test it more and feedback later but you have been of so much help to me to workaround this and Thanks so much for the pointers.